# Selecting by location and attibutes simultaneously?

Tags: python, sql

If I have a feature class ( say 'Cities') and I would like to select all features from another layer ('Incorporated Places') that nest within the cities layer and also have the same value for their 'Name' field.

How would I do this?

Specifically this will be used to remove duplicate labels between the incorporated place and its bounding city, and currently my method is to merge the centroids of the two features together and then remove duplicates between label classes, but I would prefer if there was something more elegant that would simply select the duplicate Place features instead.

I have seen other questions similar to this but the answers that were given for these suggest using ModelBuilder, which doesnt consider the fact that this process is based upon **one** selection with **two** conditions, rather than two separate selections, so as far as I  know ModelBuilder wouldn't be able to accomplish this.

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS Pro to try and do this or something else?  What other questions similar to this have you seen?  If you want this to be a coding question then please include a code snippet that illustrates what you have tried and where you are stuck.